# Runtime error while parsing a JSON byte stream with an embedded array

Tags: json, go

I am able to parse a simple JSON object into a struct, but when I try to parse an array inside that object, I am getting an `index out of range`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type jsonobject struct {
    Objects []ObjectType `json:"objects"`
}

type ObjectType struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    // Simple element
    bytes := []byte(`{ "name": "foo" }`)
    var objecttype ObjectType
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &objecttype)
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", objecttype.Name) // Results: localhost

    // Object with embedded array
    bytes = []byte(`{ "objects": [ "name": "foo" ] }`)
    jsontype := &jsonobject{}
    json.Unmarshal(bytes, &jsontype)
    fmt.Printf("Results: %v\n", jsontype.Objects[0].Name) // panic: runtime error: index out of range
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your JSON input is not what you model in Go. And so the JSON array will not be unmarshaled into `jsonobject.Objects`: it will remain `nil`; so attempting to index it will result in `index out of range` error.

Try to unmarshal from this:

```
bytes = []byte(`{ "objects": [ {"name": "foo"} ] }`)
```

Note that the elements (one element in this case) in the JSON array are also in braces (JSON object).

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vLU2582qJE).

Comment: Thank you! I realized my mistake as soon as I saw the brackets you added around the element inside the array.